# How to avoid overlapping text labels in vis.js?

Tags: html5-canvas, overlap, vis.js-network

The labels of the nodes of my graph is long. I want to make them not overlap to each other. It's more efficient than tweaking the repulsion physics. Is it possible?

In the [physics configuration](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/physics.html#), the `barnesHut` solver has `avoidOverlap` property which prevents overlapping. However this only applies to nodes, not note labels.

[image]